# Load balancing algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have load balancing problem. I need a starting point, an algorithm to get me started with the implementation of the solution below.

- I have a set of user-assigned date elements. Each element consists of a start and an end date.
- Every date element has a user-assigned calculation date (a single date greater than end date).

Let's say in day D, the date elements with calculation date D are listed, and customer requests between min(start_date) and max(end_date) of listed date elements are queried. But, when the interval between min(start_date) and max(end_date) gets bigger, performance issues arise.

What I want is to suggest a calculation date to user in order to minimize the interval between min(start_date) and max(end_date) by grouping similar date intervals together. After that, only one similar group can have the same calculation date.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do the start & end dates correlate to 'calculation date', does calculation date just have to be > end date? Do you need to give some items greater priority? Difficult to see how this is supposed to be used without a bit more information. Give a more specific uses case example of what you expect and we could be more helpful.

Comment: @user2927848, yes the calculation date just have to be greater than the end date. Calculation date only specifies which start/end date couples will be chosen to be queried for day D. Let's say D=15.12.2016 and there are 3 date elements with this calculation date: 11.01-15.2016(1), 11.01-30-2016(2) and 07-11.01.2016(3). What I want is to group (1) and (2) together. Hope this information helps.